# Graphics not found after shifting from Texlive2019 to Texlive 2020 using subfiles package with \graphicspath in main.tex

Tags: beamer, graphics, texlive, mactex, subfiles

Basic background1: MacOS Mojave10.14.6, MacTeX2019(full) and MacTeX2020(full).

Basic backgroud2: Windows10 professional, Texlive2019(full) and Texlive2020(full).

The basic file structure  as follows:

main.tex, subfile1.tex, image(folder) contained in the same home folder.

% main.tex

```
    % main.tex
    \documentclass{beamer}
     ...
     \usepackage{graphicx}
     \graphicspath{{image/}}
     \usepackage{subfiles}
     \begin{document}
    \begin{frame}
       \subfile{subfile1.tex}
    \end{frame}
   \end{document}
```

and the source code of subfile1.tex

```
% subfile1.tex
    \documentclass[main]{subfiles}
     \begin{document}
    \begin{frame}
       ...
       \includegraphics{foo.jpg}
       ...
    \end{frame}
   \end{document}
```

Everything goes well with Texlive(MacTeX)2019, but something goes wrong with Texlive(MacTex)2020, error hint: cannot find foo.jpg.  But when I move the command \graphicspath{...} from main.tex to subfile1.tex, the error disappears.

Could anyone explains why this happens?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is in fact a bug in version 1.6 of `subfiles`. See the [bug report](https://github.com/gsalzer/subfiles/issues/3#issuecomment-557930551), which is still open.

Subscribing and/or posting to that thread might help speed up a fix.